# Bootstrap 4 compatibly with angular 17

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

The project I'm working on is currently using angular 15 and we are using bootstrap 4.6.2. We plan on going to angular 17 when it releases. Is angular 17 going to support the version of bootstrap that we are using? Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Afaik, Angular does not require a bootstrap installation, so you should be able to use Angular with any bootstrap version. The better question will be whether bootstrap supports Angular 17, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.